# Spatial select on table with geometry from another table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Say I have two tables, one a table of hexagons called hexgrids and another table of other features called othertable.

I'd like to select features from othertable where they intersect features in hexgrids with value  > 0.5

Essentially I am trying to use the result of one query as a spatial selection on another table.

```
SELECT geom from hexgrids where value > 0.5 as hexselection
SELECT * from other table where ST_Within( geom, hexselection)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join using the spatial predicate and any other conditions

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table1
 JOIN table2 
  ON st_intersects(table1.geom, table2.geom)
WHERE table2.value > 0.5
```